# Change color in image - (Greenscreen in JAVA)

Tags: java, image, colors

I would like to change the color (background) from one picture to the background which comes from another picture.
Here is my code but it doesn´t work 100 %. 
Here is my current output:
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/48a6b6-1471634776.jpg

This are the images:
Original:
https://github.com/vincentclee/csci1302-software_development/blob/master/p1_green_screen/submission/sagar.jpg?raw=true

New background:
https://github.com/vincentclee/csci1302-software_development/blob/master/p1_green_screen/submission/india.jpg?raw=true

```
    public class StartGreenScreen2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String inputFile = "/Users/testGreenscreen/sagar.jpg";
        String backgroundFile = "/Users/testGreenscreen/india.jpg";

        exceptions(inputFile, backgroundFile, ".jpg", "green");

    }

    /**
     * The exceptions method accepts a String array argument. This method
     * handles exceptions that might bring up.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            Contains parameters for program execution.
     * @throws IOException
     *             For catching file problems.
     */

    public static void exceptions(String inputFile, String backgroundFile, String outputFileType, String color) throws IOException {
        // Creates 7 boolean variables, all of which have to be true for the
        // colorChanger & colorWriter to execute.
        boolean[] bool = new boolean[6];

        // args[0] try & catch statements
        try {
            new FileReader(inputFile);
            bool[0] = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Input file for color swap not found.");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("No input file specified.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There is a problem with the inputfile.");
        }

        // args[1] try & catch statements
        try {
            new FileReader(backgroundFile);
            bool[1] = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Input File not Found");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("No input file specified.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There is a problem with the inputfile.");
        }

        // args[2] try & catch statements
        try {
            if (outputFileType.contains("."))
                bool[2] = true;
            else
                System.out.println("Outfile name invalid.");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Output file not specified.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There is a problem with the outputfile.");
        }

        // args[3] try & catch statements
        try {
            if (inputFile.endsWith(".png") && backgroundFile.endsWith(".png") && outputFileType.equalsIgnoreCase(".png")) {
                bool[3] = true;
            } else if (inputFile.endsWith(".jpg") && backgroundFile.endsWith(".jpg") && outputFileType.equalsIgnoreCase(".jpg")) {
                bool[3] = true;
            } else
                System.out.println("The extension of all input files do not match!");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Extension not specified.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There is a problem with the extension.");
        }

        // args[4] try & catch statements
        try {
            if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("green") || color.equalsIgnoreCase("white")
                    || color.equalsIgnoreCase("auto"))
                bool[4] = true;
            else
                System.out.println("The spedified color is not valid.");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Color of replacement not specified.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There is a problem with the color of replacement.");
        }



        // Checks the dimensions of both the input and output image for same
        // dimensions.
        if (bool[0] && bool[1] && bool[2] && bool[3] && bool[4]) {
            BufferedImage imageIn = ImageIO.read(new File(inputFile));

            BufferedImage imageOut = ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundFile));

            if (imageIn.getWidth() == imageOut.getWidth() && imageIn.getHeight() == imageOut.getHeight())
                bool[5] = true;
            else
                System.out.println("The imgaes are not the same dimensions.");
        }

//       All arguments and dimensions have to be true for this to execute.
//       Just to be safe, this has a general exception built in.
        try {
            if (bool[0] && bool[1] && bool[2] && bool[3] && bool[4] && bool[5])
//              colorWriter(colorChanger(inputFile), backgroundFile, color);
            colorWriter(colorChanger(inputFile,backgroundFile, color), outputFileType) ;
            else
                System.out.println("Program Terminated.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("General Program Failure");
        }
    }

    /**
     * The color Changer method accepts a String array argument. This method
     * changes the colors in the picture.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            Contains parameters for program execution.
     * @return imageIn BufferedImage stream for output
     * @throws IOException
     *             For catching file problems.
     */

    public static BufferedImage colorChanger(String normalFile, String backgroundFile, String color) throws IOException {

        // Open file for replacement through Buffered Image stream.
        BufferedImage imageIn = ImageIO.read(new File(normalFile));

        // Open file background through Buffered Image stream.
        BufferedImage imageOut = ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundFile));

        // Array to store pixel information for calculation on extra credit
        int[][] pixels = new int[imageIn.getHeight()][imageIn.getWidth()];

        // Determines each pixel color and stores it into a 2D array to a
        // corresponding location.
        for (int col = 0; col < imageIn.getWidth(); col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < imageIn.getHeight(); row++) {
                pixels[row][col] = imageIn.getRGB(col, row);
            }
        }

        // Array to store different colors and their pixel counts.
        int[][] colors = new int[10000][2];
        colors[0][0] = pixels[0][0]; // Sets color value at position (0,0) to
                                        // first array.

        // Gets color information and stores it in a array, then it checks the
        // array for color, and adds count.
        // If the color does not exists, it goes down to a empty space, and
        // creates a new entry, and sets one for count.
        for (int col = 0; col < imageIn.getWidth(); col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < imageIn.getHeight(); row++) {
                boolean bool = true;
                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                    if (pixels[row][col] == colors[i][0]) {
                        colors[i][1]++;
                        bool = false;
                    }
                    if (colors[i][0] == 0) {
                        counter = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (bool) {
                    colors[counter][0] = pixels[row][col];
                    colors[counter][1]++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Prints out array of color, and number of hits greater than 10.
        System.out.println("Top Colors:");
        for (int row = 0; row < colors.length; row++) {
            if (colors[row][0] != 0 && colors[row][1] > 10)
                System.out.println(colors[row][0] + " " + colors[row][1]);
        }

        // Determine's the color with the highest pixel count.
        int high = colors[0][1];
        int backgroundColor = colors[0][0];
        for (int row = 0; row < colors.length; row++) {
            if (colors[row][1] > high) {
                backgroundColor = colors[row][0];
                high = colors[row][1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Color: " + backgroundColor + " Count: " + high);

        // Override for args[4] color selector
        if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("green")) {
            backgroundColor = -16711935;
        }

        if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("white")) {
            backgroundColor = -1;
        }

        // Color Changer
        // If the pixel on the image to be changed is the same as the color to
        // be changed, it changes the color.
        // There is also a 50 point tolerance.


        for (int col = 0; col < imageIn.getWidth(); col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < imageIn.getHeight(); row++) {
                if (imageIn.getRGB(col, row) > (backgroundColor - 8388608)
                        && imageIn.getRGB(col, row) < (backgroundColor + 8388608))
                    imageIn.setRGB(col, row, imageOut.getRGB(col, row));
            }
        }

        return imageIn;
    }

    /**
     * The colorWriter method accepts a BufferedImage stream, and a String array
     * argument.
     * 
     * @param imageIn
     *            A BufferedImage stream for inputImage.
     * @param args
     *            Contains parameters for program execution.
     * @throws IOException
     *             For catching file problems.
     */

    public static void colorWriter(BufferedImage imageIn, String ouputPath) throws IOException {
        // Generates a *.extension String.
        String outputFile = ouputPath + ".jpg";

        String testFile = "/Users/test.jpg";

        // Writes output File
        ImageIO.write(imageIn, "jpg", new File(testFile));
    }
```

How can I solve this? Or does anybody has an idea to change the code?

Comment: I would change your input: the fuzziness around the figure is a consequence of JPEG compression. Have you got a version of the image with lossless compression?

Comment: I tried this with some other pictures... Everytime the same issue not all pixels set to the new background....

Answer (score 0):

1. You lost informations by JPEG compression, better use PNG.
2. Not all pixels in your picture have same green color in background.
   [Not replaced green pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqDs2.png)
3. Your tolerance check isn't good, better use square deviation.