# Replacing section of color in image with another image - Java

Tags: java, game-engine

I am trying to create a weapon rendering system in 2D Java, pure Java. However, I ran into a problem when it came to rendering weapons onto the character. I need to render the weapon onto the position of a "green screen" on the character image. [Beta character image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LelfF.png). The light green part of that image needs to be replaced with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axHeT.png). The green portion of the character image is not static and the weapons are not always in that shape. The closest question I have seen is:
[Change color in image - (Greenscreen in JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047021/change-color-in-image-greenscreen-in-java). However, the question was not answered.

I have not done any code for this, but I was thinking of doing pixel by pixel array and getting the section, but it doesn't seem efficient with big images. I was originally planing on getting the player location on the screen and offsetting the weapon to render where it needs to be. The problem is I don't really know how to do it efficently.

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? What are you thinking of doing? We need to know what your plan is and what you have tried so far. Exactly what problem did you run into?

Comment: Personal gut feeling is, don't. Instead, define the area in which the weapon is to be displayed and simply overlay into the character image

Comment: @Keara I have not done any code for this, but I was thinking of doing pixel by pixel array and getting the section, but it doesn't seem efficient. I was originally planing on getting the player location on the screen and offsetting the weapon to render where it needs to be. The problem is I don't really know how to do it efficently.

Comment: Great! Please update your question and explain all that so everyone can see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the green pixels. Then:

1. If your character is static, do this:
   Your example weapon image has the same size as the example character image. Just keep it that way and render character and weapon at the same position every frame.
2. If you have different characters where the weapon needs to be in different locations, store the weapon offset in some file, e.g.:

   > "character1", "character1.png", 12, 14
   >
   > "character2", "character2.png", 10, 9

   or whatever else makes sense in your case. Then size the weapon image down and draw it at character position + the offsets provided in the file.
3. If you have animated characters, where the weapon position changes, store an offset for each frame.

If you really want to replace pixels in an image with pixels from another image, and with pure Java, not GPU accelerated, you must do it pixel by pixel with a simple loop.